# There exists a prime $p\equiv 1(\text{mod }3)$ such that $2$ is a cube $(\text{mod }p)$

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory

> Prove that there exist a prime $p\equiv 1(\text{mod }3)$ such that $x^3\equiv 2(\text{mod }p)$ for some $x\in\mathbb{Z}$.

I'm trying to use the fact that $a$ is a cube modulo $p$ if and only if $a^{\frac{p-1}{3}}\equiv 1(\text{mod }p)$, but I can't prove that $2^{\frac{p-1}{3}}\equiv 1(\text{mod }p)$ is necessarily true for some prime $p$. Any hints?

Comment: $4^3=64\equiv 2\pmod {31}$

Comment: Do you actually want to prove the existence of ONE prime with this property ? Or do you want to prove the property for every prime of the form $3k+1$ ?

Comment: It's for one prime. For $p=7=3(2)+1$, we have that $2$ is not a cube modulo $7$

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I guess the best way to investigate is just to factor $x^3 - 2$ for integers $x> 1.$ See when prime factors are $1 \pmod 3.$ In this little output I can see $31, 43, 439, 499$

```
    2      6 = 2 * 3
    3     25 = 5^2
    4     62 = 2 * 31
    5    123 = 3 * 41
    6    214 = 2 * 107
    7    341 = 11 * 31
    8    510 = 2 * 3 * 5 * 17
    9    727 = 727
   10    998 = 2 * 499
   11   1329 = 3 * 443
   12   1726 = 2 * 863
   13   2195 = 5 * 439
   14   2742 = 2 * 3 * 457
   15   3373 = 3373
   16   4094 = 2 * 23 * 89
   17   4911 = 3 * 1637
   18   5830 = 2 * 5 * 11 * 53
   19   6857 = 6857
   20   7998 = 2 * 3 * 31 * 43
   21   9259 = 47 * 197
```

Take a prime $$ p = u^2 + 27 v^2 $$ in integers $u,v.$ For example, $31.$
Just calculate the cubes of $1,2,3,4,5,6,7 \pmod{31},$ see what happens.

```
      1,     31,     43,    109,    127,    157,    223,    229,    277,    283,
    307,    397,    433,    439,    457,    499,    601,    643,    691,    727,
    733,    739,    811,    919,    997,   1021,   1051,   1069,   1093,   1327,
   1399,   1423,   1459,   1471,   1579,   1597,   1627,   1657,   1699,   1723,
   1753,   1777,   1789,   1801,   1831,   1933,   1999,   2017,   2089,   2113,
   2143,   2179,   2203,   2251,   2281,   2287,   2341,   2347,   2383,   2671,
   2689,   2731,   2749,   2767,   2791,   2833,   2917,   2953,   2971,
```

=====================================================================

The primes $q \equiv 1 \pmod 3$ that do not work are those $q = 4 u^2 + 2 u v + 7 v^2,$

```
 7,     13,     19,     37,     61,     67,     73,     79,     97,    103,
139,    151,    163,    181,    193,    199,    211,    241,    271,    313,
331,    337,    349,    367,    373,    379,    409,    421,    463,    487,
523,    541,    547,    571,    577,    607,    613,    619,    631,    661,
673,    709,    751,    757,    769,    787,    823,    829,    853,    859,
877,    883,    907,    937,    967,    991,   1009,   1033,   1039,   1063,
```

====================================================