# Factorizing the polynomial $x^6-2x^3+8$ over finite fields

Tags: polynomials, finite-fields

This is a very specific question. This equation came up when attempting to compute certain subgroups of groups of Lie type. The polynomial $x^6-2x^3+8$ splits over $\mathbb{F}_q$ if and only if a particular subgroup ($\mathrm{SL}_2(8).3$) embeds in a particular group of Lie type ($E_6(q)$).

More specifically, let $q$ be a prime power congruent to $1,2,4\bmod 7$, and not a power of $2$ or $3$. We ask for solutions to the equation $x^6-2x^3+8=0$ over $\mathbb{F}_q$. If $q\equiv 2\bmod 3$ then there is always a solution, but the polynomial does not split. Thus we may in addition assume that $q\equiv 1\bmod 3$. This polynomial has a solution if and only if $1+\sqrt{-7}$ is a cube in $\mathbb{F}_q$.

If it is of help, notice that $1+\sqrt{-7}$ is the sum $2(\zeta+\zeta^2+\zeta^4)$, where $\zeta$ is a primitive $7$th root of unity.

Ideally, one would like a statement of the form 'This equation has a solution if and only if $q$ is congruent to one of [...] modulo $n$'.

Comment: Any empirical data to share?

Comment: The Galois group (over $\Bbb{Q}$) is not abelian, so class field theory says that splitting of primes is not governed by congruences alone. I expect (?? but am not counting on it) a possible answer in the form: the polynomial splits modulo $p$ in such and such way, whenever we can write $p=q(x,y)$ for some binary quadratic form $q(x,y)=ax^2+bxy+cy^2$ with $a,b,c$ integer constants and $x,y$ integer variables. Alas, I have never learned the details of that.

Comment: Anyway, the Galois group over $\Bbb{Q}$ is dihedral of order twelve. Throwing out the ramified primes $p=2,3,7$ this means (by Chebotarev) that it splits completely for one prime out of twelve, remains irreducible in $1/6$ cases, factors as two cubics in $1/6$ cases, as three quadratics in $1/3$ of the cases, and as a product of two quadratics and two linear factors in $1/4$ of the cases. In terms of $q^n$ you get (total) splitting when $n$ is a multiple of $1$,$6$, $3$, $2$, $2$ respectively. Alas, it is not easy to say which primes belong to which splitting type.

Comment: So we have, suitably interpreted, total splitting for a fraction of $11/24$ of all the prime powers $q$.

Comment: So maybe it's best described as 'this group exists if and only if $\sqrt[3]{1+\sqrt{-7}}$ lies in $\mathbb{F}_q$ then. If there's no satisfactory answer using congruences any other answer might well be just as difficult to write down as that.

Comment: David, I'm afraid that may be an accurate evaluation of the situation. Anyway, it sounds like you are having fun with that embedding problem. Too bad I never got into the finite groups of Lie type stuff. I had enough problems with rep theory in the algebraic group side :-)

Comment: Well, this is the last but one group. If I could do the final one, I would have a complete list of the maximal subgroups of $F_4(q)$, $E_6(q)$ and ${}^2\!E_6(q)$ for all $q$. Although one of the possibilities has this silly cube root of a square root in it. Oh well, thank you for thinking about it.

Comment: Sounds cool. Gary Seitz visited Notre Dame in the late 80s when I was in grad school. He was excited about the program of classifying maximal subgroups and gave a few colloquium talks about it. Glad to hear that problems like this have kept group theory alive :-)

Comment: Hmm. May be my memory failed, and at the time it was about algebraic groups. Possibly it was both, but this is under a pile of rust :-/

Comment: He and Martin Liebeck finished off the algebraic groups case (i.e., where the subgroup of the algebraic group is also infinite) in 2004. They did some work on the finite case, looking for finite subgroups of the algebraic groups that are not contained in a proper infinite subgroup, and eliminated all but finitely many possibilities for the finite group. This is very closely related to the maximal subgroups of the finite simple groups. Turning that finite list into an if and only if statement is what is left.

Comment: Thanks. To give you a taste about the role of quadratic forms in problems like this [see this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2141221/11619) for a description of primes $p$ such that $x^3-2$ splits in the prime field. I don't know where that form came from. Will Jagy is knowledgeable about this. I pinged him here - just in case.

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen  indefinite 
$$ x^2 + 108 xy - 108 y^2  $$
$$ 4x^2 + 108 xy - 27 y^2  $$
$$ 7x^2 + 98 xy - 89 y^2  $$
$$ 16 x^2 + 96 xy - 45 y^2  $$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have not looked at prime powers, just primes. The four forms are indefinite, so we must require that we are using the positive primes represented by one of the forms, except for $7$ itself. Note that the third form integrally represents $-89,$ but we ignore that. I give them in "reduced" form, which means $\langle a,b,c \rangle$  with
$$ ac < 0 \; \; \; \; \mbox{AND}  \; \; \; \; b > |a+c|  $$

$$ x^2 + 108 xy - 108 y^2  $$
$$ 4x^2 + 108 xy - 27 y^2  $$
$$ 7x^2 + 98 xy - 89 y^2  $$
$$ 16 x^2 + 96 xy - 45 y^2  $$

these make a subgroup of all primitive forms of this discriminant.

I asked for the first prime above 100,000 from each of the four forms, here is factoring using gp-pari

```
parisize = 4000000, primelimit = 500000
? p = 100129
%1 = 100129
? factormod(x^6 - 2 * x^3 + 8,p)
%2 = 
[Mod(1, 100129)*x + Mod(50376, 100129) 1]

[Mod(1, 100129)*x + Mod(54756, 100129) 1]

[Mod(1, 100129)*x + Mod(71360, 100129) 1]

[Mod(1, 100129)*x + Mod(73376, 100129) 1]

[Mod(1, 100129)*x + Mod(74142, 100129) 1]

[Mod(1, 100129)*x + Mod(76506, 100129) 1]

? p = 100069
%3 = 100069
? factormod(x^6 - 2 * x^3 + 8,p)
%4 = 
[Mod(1, 100069)*x + Mod(35934, 100069) 1]

[Mod(1, 100069)*x + Mod(51775, 100069) 1]

[Mod(1, 100069)*x + Mod(69487, 100069) 1]

[Mod(1, 100069)*x + Mod(73182, 100069) 1]

[Mod(1, 100069)*x + Mod(75181, 100069) 1]

[Mod(1, 100069)*x + Mod(94717, 100069) 1]

? p = 102103
%5 = 102103
? factormod(x^6 - 2 * x^3 + 8,p)
%6 = 
[Mod(1, 102103)*x + Mod(50557, 102103) 1]

[Mod(1, 102103)*x + Mod(51024, 102103) 1]

[Mod(1, 102103)*x + Mod(64541, 102103) 1]

[Mod(1, 102103)*x + Mod(65763, 102103) 1]

[Mod(1, 102103)*x + Mod(87419, 102103) 1]

[Mod(1, 102103)*x + Mod(89108, 102103) 1]

? p = 100291
%7 = 100291
? factormod(x^6 - 2 * x^3 + 8,p)
%8 = 
[ Mod(1, 100291)*x + Mod(6281, 100291) 1]

[Mod(1, 100291)*x + Mod(56155, 100291) 1]

[Mod(1, 100291)*x + Mod(65067, 100291) 1]

[Mod(1, 100291)*x + Mod(79360, 100291) 1]

[Mod(1, 100291)*x + Mod(95251, 100291) 1]

[Mod(1, 100291)*x + Mod(99050, 100291) 1]
```

=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=

```
jagy@phobeusjunior:~/old drive/home/jagy/Cplusplus$ ./indefCycle_All_Reduced  12096 


12096    factored   2^6 * 3^3 *  7

    1.             1         108        -108   cycle length             2
    2.            -1         108         108   cycle length             2
    3.             4         108         -27   cycle length             2
    4.            -4         108          27   cycle length             2
    5.             5         106         -43   cycle length             4
    6.            -5         106          43   cycle length             4
    7.            43         106          -5   cycle length             4
    8.           -43         106           5   cycle length             4
    9.             9         102         -47   cycle length             4
   10.            -9         102          47   cycle length             4
   11.            47         102          -9   cycle length             4
   12.           -47         102           9   cycle length             4
   13.             7          98         -89   cycle length             4
   14.            -7          98          89   cycle length             4
   15.            16          96         -45   cycle length             4
   16.           -16          96          45   cycle length             4
   17.            27          90         -37   cycle length             6
   18.           -27          90          37   cycle length             6
   19.            37          90         -27   cycle length             6
   20.           -37          90          27   cycle length             6
   21.            17          88         -64   cycle length             6
   22.           -17          88          64   cycle length             6
   23.            64          88         -17   cycle length             6
   24.           -64          88          17   cycle length             6

  form class number is   24

jagy@phobeusjunior:~/old drive/home/jagy/Cplusplus$
```

=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=

```
jagy@phobeusjunior:~$ ./Conway_Positive_Primes 1 108 -108 40000 

           1         108        -108   original form 

           1         108        -108   Lagrange-Gauss reduced 



 Represented (positive) primes up to  40000

   457   673  1129  1201  2017  2713  3217  3361  3529  4057
  4201  6673  6841  7177  7417  7753  8353  8737  8929  9433
  9697 11593 11617 12553 12601 15313 17257 19009 19777 21001
 21121 21841 22129 22369 23977 24049 24889 25057 25153 25537
 26161 26497 26713 26881 27073 27241 28729 29017 30529 30577
 31033 32089 32257 33457 33769 33961 34057 34129 34273 34897
 36793 37321 37489 37633 37657 38833 39313

=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=   

jagy@phobeusjunior:~$ ./Conway_Positive_Primes 4 108 -27 40000 

           4         108         -27   original form 

           4         108         -27   Lagrange-Gauss reduced 



 Represented (positive) primes up to  40000

   421   613  1093  1117  1453  1549  2053  2221  2269  2557
  3301  3469  3733  4813  5077  5749  6133  6421  6469  6637
  7477  7669  7933  8269  8821  9013  9181  9661 10357 10957
 11173 12517 12853 13309 14149 14221 14389 14869 15373 15493
 15661 15877 16069 16741 17389 17581 18013 18181 18253 20269
 20749 21277 21757 22093 22621 23269 23557 23893 24109 24781
 25117 25237 25621 26293 27997 28429 28933 29101 29173 30181
 30517 30829 32341 32797 33013 33037 33181 33301 33469 34213
 34549 35053 35221 35317 35869 36493 36541 36877 36997 37717
 38053 38749 39181

=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=   

jagy@phobeusjunior:~$ ./Conway_Positive_Primes 7 98 -89 40000 
           7          98         -89   original form 

           7          98         -89   Lagrange-Gauss reduced 



 Represented (positive) primes up to  40000

     7   487   751   967  1663  1999  2143  2311  2647  2671
  3271  3943  4111  4159  4663  4999  5023  5623  6007  7207
  7639  7879  8647  8863  9151  9199 10039 10159 10399 10903
 11047 12511 12919 13183 13567 13591 14767 15031 15199 15439
 15583 19231 19447 20479 20743 20959 21751 21991 22159 22639
 25951 26119 26839 26959 27127 27367 27799 27847 28183 28711
 29983 30319 30367 30391 30559 30703 30871 31063 31543 32887
 32911 34183 34591 34759 35023 35527 35911 36583 36871 36919
 36943 37423 37447 37591 38047 39103 39631 39799

=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=   



jagy@phobeusjunior:~$ ./Conway_Positive_Primes 16 96 -45 40000 

          16          96         -45   original form 

          16          96         -45   Lagrange-Gauss reduced 



 Represented (positive) primes up to  40000

    67   211   739  1051  1747  2731  3019  3187  3739  3907
  4027  5779  6043  6091  6211  6619  6763  6883  7603  8059
  8467  8731  9067  9811 10243 10627 10651 10987 11299 11587
 11971 12763 12979 13003 13171 13267 14107 14683 15187 15619
 15667 16339 16699 16963 17011 17203 17299 18307 18379 18691
 18979 19051 19387 20323 21067 22171 23011 23251 23899 24691
 24859 25411 25939 26083 26251 26539 27883 28603 28723 29131
 30643 31147 31627 31963 32251 32323 32587 33091 34171 34603
 34651 34939 37507 38299 38803 39139 39883

=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=   



Primes up to 40000 for which x^6 - 2 x^3 + 8 splits
prime  mod eight mod seven  mod three  
67   eight  3   seven  4   three  1  count   1
211   eight  3   seven  1   three  1  count   2
421   eight  5   seven  1   three  1  count   3
457   eight  1   seven  2   three  1  count   4
487   eight  7   seven  4   three  1  count   5
613   eight  5   seven  4   three  1  count   6
673   eight  1   seven  1   three  1  count   7
739   eight  3   seven  4   three  1  count   8
751   eight  7   seven  2   three  1  count   9
967   eight  7   seven  1   three  1  count   10
1051   eight  3   seven  1   three  1  count   11
1093   eight  5   seven  1   three  1  count   12
1117   eight  5   seven  4   three  1  count   13
1129   eight  1   seven  2   three  1  count   14
1201   eight  1   seven  4   three  1  count   15
1453   eight  5   seven  4   three  1  count   16
1549   eight  5   seven  2   three  1  count   17
1663   eight  7   seven  4   three  1  count   18
1747   eight  3   seven  4   three  1  count   19
1999   eight  7   seven  4   three  1  count   20
2017   eight  1   seven  1   three  1  count   21
2053   eight  5   seven  2   three  1  count   22
2143   eight  7   seven  1   three  1  count   23
2221   eight  5   seven  2   three  1  count   24
2269   eight  5   seven  1   three  1  count   25
2311   eight  7   seven  1   three  1  count   26
2557   eight  5   seven  2   three  1  count   27
2647   eight  7   seven  1   three  1  count   28
2671   eight  7   seven  4   three  1  count   29
2713   eight  1   seven  4   three  1  count   30
2731   eight  3   seven  1   three  1  count   31
3019   eight  3   seven  2   three  1  count   32
3187   eight  3   seven  2   three  1  count   33
3217   eight  1   seven  4   three  1  count   34
3271   eight  7   seven  2   three  1  count   35
3301   eight  5   seven  4   three  1  count   36
3361   eight  1   seven  1   three  1  count   37
3469   eight  5   seven  4   three  1  count   38
3529   eight  1   seven  1   three  1  count   39
3733   eight  5   seven  2   three  1  count   40
3739   eight  3   seven  1   three  1  count   41
3907   eight  3   seven  1   three  1  count   42
3943   eight  7   seven  2   three  1  count   43
4027   eight  3   seven  2   three  1  count   44
4057   eight  1   seven  4   three  1  count   45
4111   eight  7   seven  2   three  1  count   46
4159   eight  7   seven  1   three  1  count   47
4201   eight  1   seven  1   three  1  count   48
4663   eight  7   seven  1   three  1  count   49
4813   eight  5   seven  4   three  1  count   50
4999   eight  7   seven  1   three  1  count   51
5023   eight  7   seven  4   three  1  count   52
5077   eight  5   seven  2   three  1  count   53
5623   eight  7   seven  2   three  1  count   54
5749   eight  5   seven  2   three  1  count   55
5779   eight  3   seven  4   three  1  count   56
6007   eight  7   seven  1   three  1  count   57
6043   eight  3   seven  2   three  1  count   58
6091   eight  3   seven  1   three  1  count   59
6133   eight  5   seven  1   three  1  count   60
6211   eight  3   seven  2   three  1  count   61
6421   eight  5   seven  2   three  1  count   62
6469   eight  5   seven  1   three  1  count   63
6619   eight  3   seven  4   three  1  count   64
6637   eight  5   seven  1   three  1  count   65
6673   eight  1   seven  2   three  1  count   66
6763   eight  3   seven  1   three  1  count   67
6841   eight  1   seven  2   three  1  count   68
6883   eight  3   seven  2   three  1  count   69
7177   eight  1   seven  2   three  1  count   70
7207   eight  7   seven  4   three  1  count   71
7417   eight  1   seven  4   three  1  count   72
7477   eight  5   seven  1   three  1  count   73
7603   eight  3   seven  1   three  1  count   74
7639   eight  7   seven  2   three  1  count   75
7669   eight  5   seven  4   three  1  count   76
7753   eight  1   seven  4   three  1  count   77
7879   eight  7   seven  4   three  1  count   78
7933   eight  5   seven  2   three  1  count   79
8059   eight  3   seven  2   three  1  count   80
8269   eight  5   seven  2   three  1  count   81
8353   eight  1   seven  2   three  1  count   82
8467   eight  3   seven  4   three  1  count   83
8647   eight  7   seven  2   three  1  count   84
8731   eight  3   seven  2   three  1  count   85
8737   eight  1   seven  1   three  1  count   86
8821   eight  5   seven  1   three  1  count   87
8863   eight  7   seven  1   three  1  count   88
8929   eight  1   seven  4   three  1  count   89
9013   eight  5   seven  4   three  1  count   90
9067   eight  3   seven  2   three  1  count   91
9151   eight  7   seven  2   three  1  count   92
9181   eight  5   seven  4   three  1  count   93
9199   eight  7   seven  1   three  1  count   94
9433   eight  1   seven  4   three  1  count   95
9661   eight  5   seven  1   three  1  count   96
9697   eight  1   seven  2   three  1  count   97
9811   eight  3   seven  4   three  1  count   98
10039   eight  7   seven  1   three  1  count   99
10159   eight  7   seven  2   three  1  count   100
10243   eight  3   seven  2   three  1  count   101
10357   eight  5   seven  4   three  1  count   102
10399   eight  7   seven  4   three  1  count   103
10627   eight  3   seven  1   three  1  count   104
10651   eight  3   seven  4   three  1  count   105
10903   eight  7   seven  4   three  1  count   106
10957   eight  5   seven  2   three  1  count   107
10987   eight  3   seven  4   three  1  count   108
11047   eight  7   seven  1   three  1  count   109
11173   eight  5   seven  1   three  1  count   110
11299   eight  3   seven  1   three  1  count   111
11587   eight  3   seven  2   three  1  count   112
11593   eight  1   seven  1   three  1  count   113
11617   eight  1   seven  4   three  1  count   114
11971   eight  3   seven  1   three  1  count   115
12511   eight  7   seven  2   three  1  count   116
12517   eight  5   seven  1   three  1  count   117
12553   eight  1   seven  2   three  1  count   118
12601   eight  1   seven  1   three  1  count   119
12763   eight  3   seven  2   three  1  count   120
12853   eight  5   seven  1   three  1  count   121
12919   eight  7   seven  4   three  1  count   122
12979   eight  3   seven  1   three  1  count   123
13003   eight  3   seven  4   three  1  count   124
13171   eight  3   seven  4   three  1  count   125
13183   eight  7   seven  2   three  1  count   126
13267   eight  3   seven  2   three  1  count   127
13309   eight  5   seven  2   three  1  count   128
13567   eight  7   seven  1   three  1  count   129
13591   eight  7   seven  4   three  1  count   130
14107   eight  3   seven  2   three  1  count   131
14149   eight  5   seven  2   three  1  count   132
14221   eight  5   seven  4   three  1  count   133
14389   eight  5   seven  4   three  1  count   134
14683   eight  3   seven  4   three  1  count   135
14767   eight  7   seven  4   three  1  count   136
14869   eight  5   seven  1   three  1  count   137
15031   eight  7   seven  2   three  1  count   138
15187   eight  3   seven  4   three  1  count   139
15199   eight  7   seven  2   three  1  count   140
15313   eight  1   seven  4   three  1  count   141
15373   eight  5   seven  1   three  1  count   142
15439   eight  7   seven  4   three  1  count   143
15493   eight  5   seven  2   three  1  count   144
15583   eight  7   seven  1   three  1  count   145
15619   eight  3   seven  2   three  1  count   146
15661   eight  5   seven  2   three  1  count   147
15667   eight  3   seven  1   three  1  count   148
15877   eight  5   seven  1   three  1  count   149
16069   eight  5   seven  4   three  1  count   150
16339   eight  3   seven  1   three  1  count   151
16699   eight  3   seven  4   three  1  count   152
16741   eight  5   seven  4   three  1  count   153
16963   eight  3   seven  2   three  1  count   154
17011   eight  3   seven  1   three  1  count   155
17203   eight  3   seven  4   three  1  count   156
17257   eight  1   seven  2   three  1  count   157
17299   eight  3   seven  2   three  1  count   158
17389   eight  5   seven  1   three  1  count   159
17581   eight  5   seven  4   three  1  count   160
18013   eight  5   seven  2   three  1  count   161
18181   eight  5   seven  2   three  1  count   162
18253   eight  5   seven  4   three  1  count   163
18307   eight  3   seven  2   three  1  count   164
18379   eight  3   seven  4   three  1  count   165
18691   eight  3   seven  1   three  1  count   166
18979   eight  3   seven  2   three  1  count   167
19009   eight  1   seven  4   three  1  count   168
19051   eight  3   seven  4   three  1  count   169
19231   eight  7   seven  2   three  1  count   170
19387   eight  3   seven  4   three  1  count   171
19447   eight  7   seven  1   three  1  count   172
19777   eight  1   seven  2   three  1  count   173
20269   eight  5   seven  4   three  1  count   174
20323   eight  3   seven  2   three  1  count   175
20479   eight  7   seven  4   three  1  count   176
20743   eight  7   seven  2   three  1  count   177
20749   eight  5   seven  1   three  1  count   178
20959   eight  7   seven  1   three  1  count   179
21001   eight  1   seven  1   three  1  count   180
21067   eight  3   seven  4   three  1  count   181
21121   eight  1   seven  2   three  1  count   182
21277   eight  5   seven  4   three  1  count   183
21751   eight  7   seven  2   three  1  count   184
21757   eight  5   seven  1   three  1  count   185
21841   eight  1   seven  1   three  1  count   186
21991   eight  7   seven  4   three  1  count   187
22093   eight  5   seven  1   three  1  count   188
22129   eight  1   seven  2   three  1  count   189
22159   eight  7   seven  4   three  1  count   190
22171   eight  3   seven  2   three  1  count   191
22369   eight  1   seven  4   three  1  count   192
22621   eight  5   seven  4   three  1  count   193
22639   eight  7   seven  1   three  1  count   194
23011   eight  3   seven  2   three  1  count   195
23251   eight  3   seven  4   three  1  count   196
23269   eight  5   seven  1   three  1  count   197
23557   eight  5   seven  2   three  1  count   198
23893   eight  5   seven  2   three  1  count   199
23899   eight  3   seven  1   three  1  count   200
23977   eight  1   seven  2   three  1  count   201
24049   eight  1   seven  4   three  1  count   202
24109   eight  5   seven  1   three  1  count   203
24691   eight  3   seven  2   three  1  count   204
24781   eight  5   seven  1   three  1  count   205
24859   eight  3   seven  2   three  1  count   206
24889   eight  1   seven  4   three  1  count   207
25057   eight  1   seven  4   three  1  count   208
25117   eight  5   seven  1   three  1  count   209
25153   eight  1   seven  2   three  1  count   210
25237   eight  5   seven  2   three  1  count   211
25411   eight  3   seven  1   three  1  count   212
25537   eight  1   seven  1   three  1  count   213
25621   eight  5   seven  1   three  1  count   214
25939   eight  3   seven  4   three  1  count   215
25951   eight  7   seven  2   three  1  count   216
26083   eight  3   seven  1   three  1  count   217
26119   eight  7   seven  2   three  1  count   218
26161   eight  1   seven  2   three  1  count   219
26251   eight  3   seven  1   three  1  count   220
26293   eight  5   seven  1   three  1  count   221
26497   eight  1   seven  2   three  1  count   222
26539   eight  3   seven  2   three  1  count   223
26713   eight  1   seven  1   three  1  count   224
26839   eight  7   seven  1   three  1  count   225
26881   eight  1   seven  1   three  1  count   226
26959   eight  7   seven  2   three  1  count   227
27073   eight  1   seven  4   three  1  count   228
27127   eight  7   seven  2   three  1  count   229
27241   eight  1   seven  4   three  1  count   230
27367   eight  7   seven  4   three  1  count   231
27799   eight  7   seven  2   three  1  count   232
27847   eight  7   seven  1   three  1  count   233
27883   eight  3   seven  2   three  1  count   234
27997   eight  5   seven  4   three  1  count   235
28183   eight  7   seven  1   three  1  count   236
28429   eight  5   seven  2   three  1  count   237
28603   eight  3   seven  1   three  1  count   238
28711   eight  7   seven  4   three  1  count   239
28723   eight  3   seven  2   three  1  count   240
28729   eight  1   seven  1   three  1  count   241
28933   eight  5   seven  2   three  1  count   242
29017   eight  1   seven  2   three  1  count   243
29101   eight  5   seven  2   three  1  count   244
29131   eight  3   seven  4   three  1  count   245
29173   eight  5   seven  4   three  1  count   246
29983   eight  7   seven  2   three  1  count   247
30181   eight  5   seven  4   three  1  count   248
30319   eight  7   seven  2   three  1  count   249
30367   eight  7   seven  1   three  1  count   250
30391   eight  7   seven  4   three  1  count   251
30517   eight  5   seven  4   three  1  count   252
30529   eight  1   seven  2   three  1  count   253
30559   eight  7   seven  4   three  1  count   254
30577   eight  1   seven  1   three  1  count   255
30643   eight  3   seven  4   three  1  count   256
30703   eight  7   seven  1   three  1  count   257
30829   eight  5   seven  1   three  1  count   258
30871   eight  7   seven  1   three  1  count   259
31033   eight  1   seven  2   three  1  count   260
31063   eight  7   seven  4   three  1  count   261
31147   eight  3   seven  4   three  1  count   262
31543   eight  7   seven  1   three  1  count   263
31627   eight  3   seven  1   three  1  count   264
31963   eight  3   seven  1   three  1  count   265
32089   eight  1   seven  1   three  1  count   266
32251   eight  3   seven  2   three  1  count   267
32257   eight  1   seven  1   three  1  count   268
32323   eight  3   seven  4   three  1  count   269
32341   eight  5   seven  1   three  1  count   270
32587   eight  3   seven  2   three  1  count   271
32797   eight  5   seven  2   three  1  count   272
32887   eight  7   seven  1   three  1  count   273
32911   eight  7   seven  4   three  1  count   274
33013   eight  5   seven  1   three  1  count   275
33037   eight  5   seven  4   three  1  count   276
33091   eight  3   seven  2   three  1  count   277
33181   eight  5   seven  1   three  1  count   278
33301   eight  5   seven  2   three  1  count   279
33457   eight  1   seven  4   three  1  count   280
33469   eight  5   seven  2   three  1  count   281
33769   eight  1   seven  1   three  1  count   282
33961   eight  1   seven  4   three  1  count   283
34057   eight  1   seven  2   three  1  count   284
34129   eight  1   seven  4   three  1  count   285
34171   eight  3   seven  4   three  1  count   286
34183   eight  7   seven  2   three  1  count   287
34213   eight  5   seven  4   three  1  count   288
34273   eight  1   seven  1   three  1  count   289
34549   eight  5   seven  4   three  1  count   290
34591   eight  7   seven  4   three  1  count   291
34603   eight  3   seven  2   three  1  count   292
34651   eight  3   seven  1   three  1  count   293
34759   eight  7   seven  4   three  1  count   294
34897   eight  1   seven  2   three  1  count   295
34939   eight  3   seven  2   three  1  count   296
35023   eight  7   seven  2   three  1  count   297
35053   eight  5   seven  4   three  1  count   298
35221   eight  5   seven  4   three  1  count   299
35317   eight  5   seven  2   three  1  count   300
35527   eight  7   seven  2   three  1  count   301
35869   eight  5   seven  1   three  1  count   302
35911   eight  7   seven  1   three  1  count   303
36493   eight  5   seven  2   three  1  count   304
36541   eight  5   seven  1   three  1  count   305
36583   eight  7   seven  1   three  1  count   306
36793   eight  1   seven  1   three  1  count   307
36871   eight  7   seven  2   three  1  count   308
36877   eight  5   seven  1   three  1  count   309
36919   eight  7   seven  1   three  1  count   310
36943   eight  7   seven  4   three  1  count   311
36997   eight  5   seven  2   three  1  count   312
37321   eight  1   seven  4   three  1  count   313
37423   eight  7   seven  1   three  1  count   314
37447   eight  7   seven  4   three  1  count   315
37489   eight  1   seven  4   three  1  count   316
37507   eight  3   seven  1   three  1  count   317
37591   eight  7   seven  1   three  1  count   318
37633   eight  1   seven  1   three  1  count   319
37657   eight  1   seven  4   three  1  count   320
37717   eight  5   seven  1   three  1  count   321
38047   eight  7   seven  2   three  1  count   322
38053   eight  5   seven  1   three  1  count   323
38299   eight  3   seven  2   three  1  count   324
38749   eight  5   seven  4   three  1  count   325
38803   eight  3   seven  2   three  1  count   326
38833   eight  1   seven  4   three  1  count   327
39103   eight  7   seven  1   three  1  count   328
39139   eight  3   seven  2   three  1  count   329
39181   eight  5   seven  2   three  1  count   330
39313   eight  1   seven  1   three  1  count   331
39631   eight  7   seven  4   three  1  count   332
39799   eight  7   seven  4   three  1  count   333
39883   eight  3   seven  4   three  1  count   334



========================
```

Comment: I tested primes (ignoring the ramified $2,3,7$) up to 150 or so, and will confirm that $p=67$ was the only splitting case.

Answer (score 2):

A comment asks for emperical data. I do not have a solution but in a search for inspiration I computed the first bunch of prime powers with $1 + \sqrt{-7}$ a cube (under the conditions $q \equiv 1 \mod 3$)

> **The $q \equiv 1 \mod 7$**
>
> 169, 211, 421, 673, 841, 967, 1051, 1093, 2017, 2143, 2269, 2311, 2647, 2731

> **The $q \equiv 2 \mod 7$**
>
> 121, 457, 751, 961, 1129, 1549, 2053, 2221, 2557, 2809, 3019, 3187, 3271

> **The $q \equiv 4 \mod 7$**
>
> 67, 361, 487, 529, 613, 739, 1117, 1201, 1453, 1663, 1747, 1999, 2671, 2713

The Magma is below for those who wish to play (apologies for ad-hoc awfulness):

```
cubes_in_class_mod_7 := function(c)
    our_cubes := [* *];
    for p in [2..10000] do
        if IsPrimePower(p) then
            if (p mod 2) eq 1 then
                if ((p mod 7) eq c) and ((p mod 3) eq 1) then
                    Fp := FiniteField(p);
                    F<x> := PolynomialRing(Fp);
                    a := Roots(x^2 + 7)[1][1];
                    is_cube := Roots(x^3 - (1 + a));
                    b := #is_cube;
                    if b eq 3 then
                       our_cubes := Append(our_cubes, p);
                    end if;
                end if;
            end if;
        end if;
    end for;

    return our_cubes;
end function;

cubes_in_class_mod_7(1);
cubes_in_class_mod_7(2);
cubes_in_class_mod_7(4);
```

Comment: @lhf further to your comment

Comment: What led me to pose the question was that I computed the answer for prime powers up to 50000 and I couldn't get any nice patterns for congruences. As has become clear, that is because there isn't one.

Comment: @Mummytheturkey, thanks

Answer (score 1):

I am a little surprised to see that my program for finding the positive primes represented by an indefinite binary quadratic form is, well, self contained. It accepts a triple of integers that are the coefficients of the original form, then applies Gauss-Lagrange reduction. Once the form is in the correct shape, it calculates large portions of the J. H. Conway Topograph. Conway's method is well suited to find just positive terms. Here is the C++ program. Note that the discriminant $b^2 - 4ac$ which must be positive but not a square, for this program must be smaller than $2^{31}-1 = 2147483647.$  I remember changing the IntSqrt function because an infinite loop occurred when finding the square root of a number too close to $2^{31}.$ From what I see, it is best to take the coefficients $|a|, |b|, |c| < 10000.$ It would not be much of a problem to call in the GMP libraries (for C++) and change all integer variables to mpz_class.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <fstream>
#include <sstream>
#include <list>
#include <set>
#include <math.h>
#include <iomanip>
#include <string>
#include <algorithm>
#include <iterator>
#include <strstream>


using namespace std;




//  this file is named     Conway_Positive_Primes.cc 
//  main writing   June 2014
  
 
// to compile
//        g++  -o     Conway_Positive_Primes     Conway_Positive_Primes.cc  -lm




void insert_primitive_reps(unsigned int a, unsigned int h, unsigned int b, unsigned int M,  set<unsigned int>  *setPtr)
{
 // cout << setw(12) << a  << setw(12) << h  << setw(12) << b << "   insert_primitive_reps"    << endl;
  if ( a <= M )
  {
    (*setPtr).insert(a);
    if ( b <= M )
    {
      (*setPtr).insert(b);
      if ( a <= M - b && h <= M - a - b)
      {
        if( a <= M - a - h ) insert_primitive_reps(a, h + 2 * a, a + b + h, M, setPtr);
        if( b <= M - b - h ) insert_primitive_reps(a + b + h, h + 2 * b,b, M, setPtr);
         // comment: once a+b+h <= M, min(2a+h, 2b+h) <= M
      }  // if a + b + h
    } // if  b
  } // if a

} // end insert_primitive_rep



int IntSqrt(int i)
{
  // cerr << "called intsqrt  with   " << i << endl;
  if ( i <= 0 ) return 0;
  else if ( i <= 3) return 1;
  else if ( i >= 2147395600) return 46340;
  else
  {
    float r;
    r = 1.0 * i;
    r = sqrt(r);
    int root = (int) ceil(r);
    while ( root * root   <= i ) ++root;
    while ( root * root   > i ) --root;
    return  root ;
  }
}


string stringify(int x)
 {
   ostringstream o;
   o << x  ;
   return o.str();
 }


string Factored(unsigned int i)
{
  string fac;
  fac = " = ";
  int p = 2;
 unsigned int temp = i;
  if (temp < 0 )
  {
    temp *= -1;
    fac += " -1 * ";
  }

  if ( 1 == temp) fac += " 1 ";
  if ( temp > 1)
  {
    int primefac = 0;
    while( temp > 1 && p * p <= temp)
    {
      if (temp % p == 0)
      {
        ++primefac;
        if (primefac > 1) fac += " * ";
         fac += stringify( p) ;
        temp /= p;
        int exponent = 1;
        while (temp % p == 0)
        {
          temp /= p;
          ++exponent;
        } // while p is fac
        if ( exponent > 1)
        {
          fac += "^" ;
          fac += stringify( exponent) ;
        }
      }  // if p is factor
      ++p;
    } // while p
    if (temp > 1 && primefac >= 1) fac += " * ";
    if (temp > 1 ) fac += stringify( temp)  ;
  } // temp > 1
  return fac;
} // Factored


int PrimeQ(int i)
{
  if ( i < 0 ) i *= -1;
  if ( i <= 3) return 1;
  else
  {
    int boo = 1;
    int j = 2;

    while (boo && j * j   <= i )
    {
      if ( i %  j  == 0) boo = 0;
      ++j;
    }
    return boo;
  }
}


int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
  if ( argc != 6) cout << "Usage: ./Conway_Positive_Primes A B C      Bound    Modulus " << endl;
  else {
 


  int a,b,c, discr;
     int N,M;
    a = atoi(argv[1]);
        b = atoi(argv[2]);
    c = atoi(argv[3]);
   M = atoi(argv[4]);
     N = atoi(argv[5]);
 cout << setw(12) << atoi(argv[1])  << setw(12) << atoi(argv[2])  << setw(12) << atoi(argv[3]) << "   original form " << endl    << endl;
      int d = b * b - 4 * a * c ;
      int droot = IntSqrt(d) ;
      if ( d <= 0) cout << "nonpositive discriminant  " << d << endl << endl;
       if (d == droot * droot) cout << "square discriminant  " << d << endl << endl;
 
      if (d > 0 && d != droot * droot)
      {



      int aa,bb,cc;
      while ( a <= 0 || c >= 0 || b <= abs(a+c) )
      {
        int delta, cAbs;
       cAbs = c;
        if (cAbs < 0) cAbs *= -1;

       delta =   (b + droot)/( 2 * cAbs)  ;
  if (c < 0) delta *= -1;
     aa = c ; bb = 2 * c * delta - b ; cc =  c * delta * delta - b * delta + a ;
       a = aa; b = bb; c = cc;
       } // while not reduced with a > 0


  cout << setw(12) << a  << setw(12) << b  << setw(12) << c << "   Lagrange-Gauss reduced " << endl    << endl;


        int a_old = a;
        int b_old = b;
        int c_old = c;

        int goon = 1;
       

set<unsigned int>  S;





        while (goon )
        {
         
      
         int newval = a+b+c;

          if ( newval > 0 )
          {
       //      cout << setw(65) << b + 2 * a << endl;
             insert_primitive_reps(a, b + 2 * a,newval ,M,  &S); // note ampersand
             b+= 2 * c ;
            
             a = newval;

           } // newval > 0
         else if ( newval < 0 )
          {
     //        cout << setw(5) << -1 * ( b + 2 * c) << endl;
 
             b+= 2 * a ;
             c = newval;
 
           } // newval < 0

  
         goon = (a != a_old)  || (b != b_old)  || (c != c_old)  ;

        } // while goon

     
  cout << endl << endl << " Represented (positive) primes up to  " << M << endl << endl;
 set<unsigned int> mods ;

 int rount = 0;
 set<unsigned int>::iterator iterU;
 for(iterU = S.begin() ;   iterU != S.end() ; ++iterU)
    {
      
      unsigned int p = *iterU;
     if ( p > 1 && PrimeQ(p) )
      {
       cout << setw(6) << p ;
       ++rount;
       if (rount % 10 == 0 ) cout << endl;
     // cout << setw(12) << p << setw(12) << p %  N << endl ;
      mods.insert( p % N);
      

      } // if prime
    }

  int count = 0;
  cout << endl << endl;
  cout << "=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=   " << endl;
  cout<< " these are the collection of remainders when dividing by   " << N << endl << endl;
 for(iterU = mods.begin() ;   iterU != mods.end() ; ++iterU )
  {
    int    u = *iterU ;
    ++count;
    {
      cout << setw(7) << u  ;
      if (0 == count % 10) cout << endl;
    }
  } // for iterU

  cout << endl << endl;

   


  cout << endl << endl << " Represented (positive) primes up to  " << M <<  "  and value mod    " << N << endl << endl;
 cout << setw(12) << atoi(argv[1])  << setw(12) << atoi(argv[2])  << setw(12) << atoi(argv[3]) << "   original form " << endl    << endl;
       } // not square


    } // else argc
    return 0 ;
}





 
//  g++  -o     Conway_Positive_Primes     Conway_Positive_Primes.cc  -lm
```